# How to run a program in batch file with parameters?

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I start this batch file

```
START "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe" --instance Pie64
```

then windows shows the eror

> Can not find "--instance". Check if the name spelled correctly and try it again.

Comment: Use ```START "HDPlayer" "%ProgramFiles%\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe" --instance Pie64```, where the string `"HDPlayer"` can be any title, even an empty one, `""`.

Comment: With the `START` command, the first doublequoted option is generally understood to be the **title**, so your code is trying to run the command `--instance` with argument `Pie64` and with `C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe` as its title string. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `start /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to see its usage information.

Comment: I hope you aren't expecting me to resolve another issue now. Assisting you once does not tie me into a contract as your personal assistant.

Comment: @Compo the issue is successfully solved, thanks